# Prevent Iframe form openin in New Window

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am uplaoding a JSPForm using iFrame.The code is as follows,

```
function directConvert(form, action_url, div_id){               
        // Create the iframe...
        var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
        iframe.setAttribute("id", "upload_iframe");     
        iframe.setAttribute("name", "upload_iframe");
        iframe.setAttribute("width", "0");
        iframe.setAttribute("height", "0");
        iframe.setAttribute("border", "0");
        iframe.setAttribute("style", "width: 0; height: 0; border: none;");
        // Add to document...
        form.parentNode.appendChild(iframe);
        //window.frames['upload_iframe'].name = "upload_iframe";     
        iframeId = document.getElementById("upload_iframe");     
        // Add event...

        var eventHandler = function () {     
                if (iframeId.detachEvent) iframeId.detachEvent("onload", eventHandler);
                else iframeId.removeEventListener("load", eventHandler, false);             
                // Message from server...    

                if (iframeId.contentDocument) {                
                    content = iframeId.contentDocument.body.innerHTML;
                } else if (iframeId.contentWindow) {                    
                    content = iframeId.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
                } else if (iframeId.document) {                 
                    content = iframeId.document.body.innerHTML;
                }               
                document.getElementById(div_id).innerHTML = content;     
                // Del the iframe...
                setTimeout('iframeId.parentNode.removeChild(iframeId)',50);
            }

        if (iframeId.addEventListener) iframeId.addEventListener("load", eventHandler, true);
        if (iframeId.attachEvent) iframeId.attachEvent("onload", eventHandler);  

        // Set properties of form...
        form.setAttribute("target", "upload_iframe");
        form.setAttribute("action", action_url);
        form.setAttribute("method", "post");
        form.setAttribute("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
        form.setAttribute("encoding", "multipart/form-data");  
        form.submit();      
    }
```

The Form is submitting properly but after that if there is any action like checking radio buttons in the page leads to opening the application in New Window.How to prevent it from opening in New Window?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why radio buttons would cause any problem, but if the form is submitting, the problem is probably that the form 'target' no longer exists.

```
form.setAttribute("target", "upload_iframe");
```

The "upload_iframe" element is removed from the DOM in your load event handler. Try setting the target to "_self" once the iframe has been removed.

Form target docs: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_target.asp